# async _flush won't fire an end event

Tags: javascript, node.js

The 'end' event is never fired, unleass a 'data' handler is added or `pipe.resume()` is called, as shown here:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_compatibility_with_older_node_js_versions

But we are not only calling `pipe.end()` as opposed to the example there, we are also calling
`pipe.read()` repeatedly as explained here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

```js
const { Transform } = require('stream')

class Pipe extends Transform {
    _transform(data, encoding, callback) {
        console.log('_transform', data.toString())
        this.push(data)
        callback()
    }

    _flush(callback) {
        process.nextTick(callback)
    }
}

const pipe = new Pipe()

pipe.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('on finish')
})

pipe.on('end', () => {
    console.log('on end')
})

pipe.write('foo')

console.log('pipe.end()')
pipe.end()

console.log('read 1', pipe.read().toString())
console.log('read 2', pipe.read())
```

output:

```
_transform foo
pipe.end()
read 1 foo
read 2 null
on finish
```

We would expect to see an 'on end' log, even without data handler and `pipe.resume()` since we are calling `pipe.read()`.

Furthermore, using

```js
_flush(callback) {
    callback()
}
```

instead works fine:

```
_transform foo
pipe.end()
read 1 foo
read 2 null
on finish
on end
```

So it seems this issue is only present with asynchronous _flush code

What is going on there?

node version 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I forgot to update this question.

Here is a working version, the end event is only fired after the callback of _flush is called, and after the end event is consumed (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34520#issuecomment-664646155)

```js
const { Transform } = require('stream')

async function main() {
    let resolveFlush
    const flush = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolveFlush = resolve
    })

    class Pipe extends Transform {
        _transform(data, encoding, callback) {
            console.log('_transform', data.toString())
            this.push(data)
            callback()
        }

        _flush(callback) {
            process.nextTick(() => {
                console.log('flush callback')
                callback()
                resolveFlush()
            })
        }
    }

    const pipe = new Pipe()

    pipe.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('on finish')
    })

    pipe.on('end', () => {
        console.log('on end')
    })

    pipe.write('foo')

    console.log('pipe.end()')
    pipe.end()

    console.log('read 1', pipe.read().toString())
    console.log('read 2', pipe.read())

    await flush
    console.log('read 3', pipe.read())
}

main()
```

outputs

```
_transform foo
pipe.end()
read 1 foo
read 2 null
on finish
flush callback
read 3  null
on end
```